# MVC2 Update Entity Framework Database using JQuery JSON Object (Please Help me get this working)

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-5

I'm new to updating Enity Framework objects using JQuery and JSON.  I created the entity objet in a console app and the update function and it works.  I tried tranfering over to my web app and I can't get it to update through my web app.

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(int rowID)
    {
        var keyValues = new KeyValuePair<string, object>[] {
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("QUICKFIX_ID", rowID)
        };

        var key = new EntityKey("CSCEntities.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar", keyValues);

        var quickfixtbl = (tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar)db.GetObjectByKey(key);
        int usrcount = (int)quickfixtbl.USECOUNT_NR;

        // update
        usrcount = usrcount + 1;

        // find the row to update using the ID
        tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar quickFix = (from x in db.tbl_Quickfix_Toolbar
                                         where x.QUICKFIX_ID == rowID
                                         select x).First();
        quickFix.USECOUNT_NR = usrcount;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

and here is the JQueryfunction that calls my controller:

```
//Updates the use count in the List


function Update() {
  $.ajax({
          url: "/csc/devapp1/Home/Update",
          type: 'POST',
          data: "rowID=" +id,
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          success: function (data) {
                   alert('Details Updated Successfully');
          },
          error: function () {
                   alert('Unable to Update for the Given ID');
          }
   });
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, I been going at this for weeks and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

```
data: "rowID=" +id,
```

to this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ rowID : id }),
```

And probably your `URL` is wrong:

change this:

```
url: "/csc/devapp1/Hom/Update/",
```

to this:

```
url: '/Home/Update',
```

And it should work

Comment: You could send in a value to your js for url also. So Url would be something like var url=@Url.Action("Update","controller",new {rowID=@Model.ID}); js.doSomething({url=url});

Comment: I updated the questions URL.  I noticed I misspelled the URL *Home controller.  I'm using JQGrid and when I tried using @Url.Action("Update","Home") it broke my code.  The JQGrid doesn't display anymore.

Comment: It should but I'm not getting any updates to the DB using the Entity Framework.  This is why I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how I can go about a different way to get this to work.